# Perceptrons: Functions not learnable without bias

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I am trying to determine which functions are not learnable without a bias when building a perceptron. The set of functions I need to evaluate is {NOT, OR, AND}.

Could someone help interpret these results?

AND FUNCTION

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sbuj.jpg

OR FUNCTION

I get a divide by 0 error in my script.

NOT FUNCTION

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVcXw.jpg

It would appear that the AND function does not crash like the OR function but the end result is incorrect. The OR function simply won't graph due to a divide by 0 error. The NOT function appears to still be learnable.

If desired, I can post my python script with how I generated these graphs. I am using a sigmoid activate function.

Comment: A function can be learned without bias if there is a hyperplane through the origin which separates the YES values from the NO values. You can check whether this is possible for your three functions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It would appear that only NOT function would be learnable then. This is because this is the only function that can be seperated with a hyperplane through the origin. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, that's also what I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a bias, your perceptron learns the function

$$y = w_1 \cdot x$$

This means the decision boundary is a line through (0, 0).

### AND

$y, x, w_1 \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Function table:

```
x_1 x_2 y
---------
0   0   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

This is not learnable.

> I am using a sigmoid activate function.

Without a hidden layer, a Perceptron is still a linear classifier.